# How to append an argument to an external command in init.el?

Tags: org-babel, debugging, shell

I <sup>1</sup>must append a config file to <sup>2</sup>package command, required as `-p
puppeteer-config.json`. In my init.el, I tried changing the native command as
shown below:

From:

```
(setq ob-mermaid-cli-path "~/node_modules/.bin/mmdc")
```

To:

```
(setq ob-mermaid-cli-path "~/node_modules/.bin/mmdc -p puppeteer-config.json")
```

Evaluating the code block results in:

```
org-babel-execute:mermaid: could not find mermaid.cli executable at ~/node_modules/.bin/mmdc -p puppeteer-config.json
```

I'm aware of <sup>3</sup>shell-quote-arguments, though couldn't figure out how to use them
to solve my problem.

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> https://github.com/mermaidjs/mermaid.cli#user-content-linux-sandbox-issue

<sup>2</sup> https://github.com/arnm/ob-mermaid

<sup>3</sup> https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Shell-Arguments.html

Comment: It looks like you could try a SQL infection trick, like `~/node_modules/.bin/mmdc\" -p \"puppeteer-config.json"` ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with mermaid, but did you consider making a wrapper script that has the arguments hard coded (assuming those arguments will not change)?

Answer (score 2):

[`org-babel-execute:mermaid`](https://github.com/arnm/ob-mermaid/blob/5deaea757b3a5de874d94e40c03116fbc8195308/ob-mermaid.el#L44) constructs its shell command like so:

```el
(concat (shell-quote-argument (expand-file-name ob-mermaid-cli-path))
        " -i " (org-babel-process-file-name temp-file)
        " -o " (org-babel-process-file-name out-file))
```

So there isn't any facility to specify other options.

The sensible thing to do is to submit a feature request or patch to `ob-mermaid` to provide a new user option for configuring custom arguments for this command.

The workaround is to do what Beetle B has suggested, and write a shell script like:

```
#!/bin/sh
/path/to/node_modules/.bin/mmdc -p puppeteer-config.json "$@"
```

and then point the `ob-mermaid-cli-path` variable at the path to that script.